# Bigquery - select timestamp as human readable datetime

Tags: google-bigquery

How to select timestamp(stored as seconds) as human readable datetime in Google Bigquery?

**schema**

```
id(STRING) | signup_date(TIMESTAMP)
```

I wrote a query using `DATE` function, but getting error

```
SELECT DATE(create_date) FROM [accounts]
```

> Error: Invalid function name: DATE; did you mean CASE?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post also your schema, as I don't see anything wrong and it works for me.

Comment: please see my updated question with schema provided.

Comment: I still don't see anything wrong here, could you share your full query, as maybe some other syntax confuses you and the parser.

Comment: I tried a very simple query, but still getting the error. please see my updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found a working solution from Bigquery reference page. Basically BigQuery stores `TIMESTAMP` data internally as a `UNIX timestamp` with microsecond precision.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(date) FROM ...
```